# Загрузка background на сайте

Tags: html, css, css3

В стилях jsp-страницы, в body для background ставлю картинку

```
body {
    background: url(/img/min.jpg);
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы при переходе на страницу background загружался первым? А то с начала загружаются все элементы страницы на белом фоне, даже картинки из бд подтягиваются раньше и только потом(последним) background.

Comment: Никак. Что бы не было белого, добавьте какой-то цвет

Comment: печально.......

Comment: Это точно......

Comment: @Yuri, почему?)

Comment: Решения для вашей проблемы нет, но можно это обыграть: сделайте из фоновой картинки thumbnail, закатайте его в base64, затем используйте его вместо фона и заблюрьте фон через `filter: blur(5px)`. Затем, как сказано в [этом ответе](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/4981937), подгрузите картинку, и после загрузки замените thumbnail на оригинал, а блюр уберите через transition. На выходе получится, что когда юзер открывает страницу, у него заблюрен фон, но когда фоновая картинка подгружается, то блюр плавно исчезает.

Comment: @terron, а progressive jpeg не проще использовать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, проще, но это немного о другом. Он же из шакалистого будет постепенно в обычный превращаться по ходу загрузки. А я предлагаю из превьюшки сделать заблюренный фон, который на момент загрузки оригинального фона будет смотреться поаккуратнее. Также если прогрессивный жипег засунуть в CSS, то он также начнет грузиться с задержкой, как описал автор вопроса. А превьюшка в base64 подгрузится мгновенно.

Answer (score 2):

Предположу, что может сработать что-то такое (но я бы за это руки поотрывал, наверное):

```
<script>
~function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', "img.jpg", false);
  xhr.send()
}();
</script>
</head>
<body style="background:url(img.jpg)">
```

Другой вариант (тоже не очень):

```
<body style="background:url(img.jpg)">
<script>
~function() {
  document.body.style.display = 'none'; // Не в css - вдруг скрипты отключены
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', "img.jpg", true);
  xhr.onload = function () { document.body.style.display = 'block' };
  xhr.send();
}();
</script>
```

В обоих случаях надо не забыть правильно настроить кэширование.

Обращаю внимание, что во втором случае скрипт должен быть в начале `body`.
А вот в первом на эту тему надо подумать.

Comment: >(но я бы за это руки поотрывал, наверное). Так зачем учить плохому, если самому не хочется подобное испытать на себе? Зачем продавать оружие, которое будет использовано против себя? Сиюминутная выгода (понты, погоны. лайки и тп) превыше всего?

Comment: @SeVlad, ситуации бывают разные.

Comment: А подумать, что это паблик? Ну  я так и думал - лайки важнее :(.

Comment: @SeVlad, ещё раз. Ситуации бывают разные и использование любого решения остаётся на совести использовавшего. Предупреждение есть. Второй вариант чем-то смахивает на всякие `ng-cloak`, так что не так уж он и плох, возможно. Ну т. е. белый текст на белом фоне не сильно то и лучше, наверное.

Answer (score 2):

**Во-первых**, советую вам оптимизировать изображения, если вы вдруг этого не делаете. Для этого есть множество онлайн-сервисов ([TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/), например), софта или плагинов для сборщиков проектов. Если время загрузки фонового изображения настолько велико, то, вероятнее всего, изображение занимает очень много места.

**Во-вторых**, рекомендую ознакомиться с концепцией [Critical CSS](http://prgssr.ru/development/razbiraemsya-s-kritichnym-css.html). Вкратце, суть её состоит в том, что вы выносите цсс первого экрана инлайном и он влетает гораздо быстрее, снижая время первой отрисовки.

**В-третьих**, я крайне не рекомендую отдавать наивысший приоритет загрузке фонового изображения. Если вы сделаете всё, чтобы картинка загружалась первой, в ущерб всему остальному контенту, то это негативно отразится на UX. Если без фонового изображения страница является неполноценной, то это задача дизайнеру. Просто поставьте цвет фона, аналогичный среднему цвету картинки, необходимому блоку, чтобы можно было прочесть текст — этого достаточно в 99% случаев.